# How friction, tension, spring forces are derived forces from electromagnetic force?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, friction, spring

I always imagined friction force causing due to some irregularities in the plane like this,

[image]

but lately I am having a hard time thinking "How it is a derived force from electromagnetic force?"

Comment: The model that links microscopic electrostatic forces with bulk mechanical forces is the [pair potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential).

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thank you!!!